# Copying values from one column to another when the new column value is empty

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `context` there are two columns `type1` and `Context Interpretation`.

`type1` has some empty values, I want to copy the values from `Context Interpretation` column to the `type1` column when that column is empty.

So far I have this:

```
context.loc[context['type1']==''] = context['Context Interpretation']
```

How far away am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thow `type1` into `loc`:

```
context.loc[context['type1']=='', 'type1'] = context['Context Interpretation']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fillna() function, which will fill in empty values with your value of choice:

```
context["type1"].fillna(inplace=True, value=context["Context Interpretation"])
```